# Show that $A^k$ approaches a matrix as $k\to\infty$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems, markov-chains

Given 
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
0.4 & -0.3 \\
0.4 & 1.2 \\
\end{bmatrix},$$

how can it be explained that $A^k$ approaches

$$\begin{bmatrix}
-0.5 & -0.75 \\
1.0 & 1.5 \\
\end{bmatrix} ?$$

I understand that diagonalization could be done, such that $A^k=S J^k S^{-1}$, however I cannot relate this to Markov chains/discrete dynamical systems. If our steady state is $x_k$, then $x_k=A^k x_0$ which holds for $x_0=\{1\}$. How can this be used to explain the exponentiation though?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Just take the limit $k \to \infty$ on both sides of $A^k = S J^k S^{-1}$ and you will get the answer.

Comment: @PratyushSarkar I was fairly confused how to treat this question; it was posed at the end of a section on "Discrete Dynamical Systems." I had figured there was an approach relating to this topic, beyond just the diagonalization trick, that could explain it.

Comment: Multiplying the candidate by A and getting A hints at this.

Comment: Each step of the evolution of the system state involves multiplying the current state vector by $A$.

Comment: This is not a converging matrix since it has an eigenvalue greater than unity. To prove this you need to study Lyupanov theory for discrete dynamical systems.

Comment: @BilalJafarKaraki The eigenvalues are $1$ and $0.6$, hence the convergence of $A^k$.

Comment: @Brandon Why do you try to relate to some Markov chain, a matrix which is neither a transition matrix nor a generator matrix?